# How is ngFor able to loop through and find some objects while others are undefined?

Tags: angular

So this problem is driving me crazy. My friend has some code, and when he uses `*ngFor` and loops through, he is able to find the properties of his object. He uses an array that contains an object just like I am doing.

When I try to do it, it comes out `undefined`.

I've tried debugging the code and the problem is that the loop does not find the properties.

**app-user-item component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-item',
  templateUrl: './user-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-item.component.scss']
})
export class UserItemComponent implements OnInit {


@Input() fields : string[];


  constructor() { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app-user-item template:**

```
<h1>fields.name</h1>
<h1>fields.destination</h1>
```

app-user-list component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, } from '@angular/core';
import { stringify } from '@angular/core/src/render3/util';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-list',
  templateUrl: './user-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-list.component.scss']
})
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {

  fields = [{
    name: "Ian",
    destination: "USA"
  },
  {
    name: "Jesse",
    destination: "Japan"
  }

];



  constructor() {


   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app-user-list template:**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor= "let field of fields">

    <app-user-item [fields] = "field"> </app-user-item>

  </li>

</ul>
```

The problem is I am getting `undefined` for `fields.name` and `fields.destination`

I am able to `console.log(fields)` and I get an object, but why is it not reading the property?

Comment: can you share app-user-item component and template?

Comment: Just updated, let me know if that is enough.

Comment: I added all the code now, I get an undefined for fields.name and fields.destination, but if I only interpolate with {{fields}} I get a loop of "Object object"

Comment: @Ne0 `console.log('fields : ', this.fields )` in your `ngOnChanges` of `app-user-item` and see when your child component is initialized it has value from parent component or not? It may be a matter of angular change detection.

Answer (score 0):

add the following edits to your files

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-item',
  templateUrl: './user-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-item.component.scss']
})
export class UserItemComponent implements OnInit {


// Correctly type your array.
@Input() fields: {name: string, destination:string}[];


  constructor() { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

// I assume this is not inside the same file if so please comment it out

// fields = [{
//    name: "Ian",
//    destination: "USA"
//      },
//      {
//    name: "Jesse",
//    destination: "Japan"
//  }

//];
```

```html
    <!-- Add Curly Braces -->


<h1>{{fields.name}}</h1>
<h1>{{fields.destination}}</h1>
```

Comment: Please check the code again, I added all the code now so it will make more sense.

Comment: Please check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctvju1 . it is basically a copy paste of my answer here and it is working fine.

Comment: Do you know what was causing it to be undefined before? Because my friend had it typed Input() fields : string[]; 

and that worked. Was I defining it incorrectly in typescript?

Comment: Yes as clearly this is not an array of strings this is an array of objects with properties name and destination

Answer (score 0):

You missed the double curly braces for string interpolation - needs to be like this -

```
{{fields.name}}
```

Same goes for next property

```
{{fields.destination}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using code below

```js
/*func3.component.ts*/
import  {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:'box-func3',
    templateUrl:"./func3.component.html",
    styleUrls:['./func3.component.scss']
})

export class Fun3Component{
    dataObject=[
        {
            "name":"JON SNOW",
            "image":"https://www.elle.vn/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/24/elle-viet-nam-game-of-thrones-02.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name":"SANSA STARK",
            "image":"https://www.elle.vn/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/24/elle-viet-nam-game-of-thrones-04.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name":"ARYA STARK",
            "image":"https://www.elle.vn/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/24/elle-viet-nam-game-of-thrones-06.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name":"BRAN STARK",
            "image":"https://www.elle.vn/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/24/elle-viet-nam-game-of-thrones-08.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name":"THEON GREYJOY",
            "image":"https://www.elle.vn/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/24/elle-viet-nam-game-of-thrones-10.jpg"
        }

    ]
}




/*func4.component.ts*/
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:"box-func4",
    templateUrl:"./func4.component.html",
    styleUrls:['./func4.component.scss']
})

export class Func4Component{
    @Input() dataName:any=[]
    constructor(){
        
    }
}
```

```html
/*template func3.component.html */
<div class="container">
    <box-func4 [dataName]="dataObject"></box-func4>
</div>

/*template func4.component.html */
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let item of dataName">
        <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
        <img [src]="item.image" style="width: 100%"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you missed curly braces (`{{fields.name}}` & `{{fields.destination}}`) as everyone answered.
And it will work but your input is not an array of string (`String[]`) its an object you are inserting into the `app-user-item` component from `ngFor`.
Its good to change it to

```
@Input() field: {name: string, destination:string};
```

and

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor= "let field of fields">
    <app-user-item [field] = "field"> </app-user-item>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But the object is contained within an array. Would you consider this an array that houses an object?

Comment: fields is an array of objects (`{name: string, destination:string}[]`). so when we loop it `*ngFor= "let field of fields"` the field will be an object(`{name: string, destination:string}`).

Answer (score 0):

I changed your user-item.component.html as

```
<h1>{{fields.name}}</h1>
<h1>{{fields.destination}}</h1>
```

and user-item.component.ts

```
@Input() fields;
```

I made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y2zppj) for your help.